# Pass variable from jQuery to WebMethod (Authentication failed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I create a new WebForms Application in VS2013. I didn't change anything and created a simple page. I want to load this table on client side when user clicks button

```
<table id="tblHelpRow">
        <thead>
            <tr class="title">
                <th>F2
                </th>
                <th>F3
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="helpRowBody">         
            <%=MyRow %>  
        </tbody>
    </table>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" onclick="fnEdit();" />
```

This is my script code:

```
function fnEdit() {
    BindGridView();
};
function BindGridView() {
    rowid = {rowID:2};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetRow",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: param,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                 alert(data);
            }
        });
}
```

I have a WebMethod in my code-behind which stores result in the public property. DataSource I store in session, but rowID I need to pass from jquery.

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetRow(int rowID)
        {
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["SourceData"];
                MyRow = "<tr>" +
                "<td>" + dt.Rows[rowID]["F2"].ToString() + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + dt.Rows[rowID]["F3"].ToString() + "</td>" +
                "</tr>";
            return "done";
    }
```

But I don't get any result. When I have put the breakpont in success I got "Authentication failed" error and this webmethod wasn't executed. What's the problem? I didn't change ant Authentication settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the ScriptMethod attribute. You are specifying a POST action type but I believe the ScriptMethod forces the request to be a GET by default. Also, I believe your param needs to be a JSON string instead of just an integer:

```
var param = {rowID:2};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/GetRow",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(param),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
         alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you throw a debug breakpoint in the web method and see if it's even hitting it?

Comment: Just threw this together myself. Definitely need the param in JSON format. The ScriptMethod didn't matter. I had to comment out the MyRow because I am not doing anything with that and I didn't build and store the datatable to session so it's always null. But, it does return "done" and enters the WebMethod. I am also assuming your markup is "OnClientClick" and you're preventing the postback - sample above is not that way.

Comment: Thanks... Looks like the problem in my VS. I will try recreate this project and try again

Answer (score 1):

In my VS2013 web forms project the **culprit** turned out to be:

`var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings {AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent};`

Using default settings for FriendlyUruls solved the problem--do not use RedirectMode.Permanent.

The ajax call like this, where the data params are complex.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: applicationBaseUrl + "mypage.aspx/Calc",
        data: params     // data is json
    }).success(function (data, status, xhr) {
        //...
    }).error(function (xhr, status, error) {
        //...
    });
```

The WebMethod like this

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static string Calc(IEnumerable<AiApp> aiApps, Guid guid)
    { //...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetRow",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {rowID:2},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
             alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Give more explanation instead of giving in single keywords